# How to remove a specific post from "Top Network Posts"?

Tags: feature-request, support, profile-page

The new user profile view has a list of that user's top posts from across the network. 99% of the time it's a great way to get an idea of what a user's most interesting or popular contributions are - but what if there's a post in this list you don't want there?

In my case, at some point in the not-distant future I intend to set up professional profiles for myself, and I'd like to have [my SE profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/178621/user568458?tab=profile)  linked to these. 95% of my posts reflect my professional interests and I think would give a good impression to the kind of professional contacts I'd want to make.

Except for [what was] my very "top network post"... which is an answer on a "how to not do X socially inappropriate thing" type Workplace question which attracted a swarm of upvotes after the question went viral.

It's absolutely not a problem I relate to or have experience with. I was able to help because it reminded me of something I'd read about in psychology class, and I was happy to help because the asker was clearly aware that they had a problem and was doing the right thing by seeking help to solve it. I'm happy to have written it, but sitting at the very top of that list, it gives an awkward and misleading first impression of the sorts of problem I associate myself with.

With it removed, my top posts list [as it was when this question was written] would give a nice natural overview of my professional interests. With it there (and also the other workplace question in my list, which I'd probably also remove) someone glancing at that list might suspect that I'm someone who struggles to cope with the modern world.

Is there any way I can control what appears in my 'top network posts' list? e.g. remove specific posts, or limit it to only specific SE sites?

---

*This is a "`support` if it's possible, `feature-request` if it's not possible" question, please feel free to re-tag.*

Comment: You can hide the community (click the edit list link at the bottom of the communities list), which will hide all questions from it as well.

Comment: @Oded that sounds like a good compromise - but I can't find the "communities list" you refer to. Can you develop this comment into an answer?

Comment: I mean in your profile page, above the hot network questions. Alternatively, go to "edit profile & settings" then to "hide communities".

Comment: I found the hide communities one, it's fixed it on my profile page, but not this page http://stackexchange.com/users/275533/user568458?tab=top - is that because of caching?

Comment: No, not caching. It is designed that way. It is not a true privacy setting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Top posts taken from hidden communities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277279/top-posts-taken-from-hidden-communities)

Comment: @StevenVascellaro: That seems to be a bug report in the answer given here, not a dupe at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though there is no way to hide a specific post, you can hide the whole community (this will hide it on any Q&A site, but if someone will go to your network profile, it will still be visible).

You can do this following the "Edit list" under the communities list on the profile page.

> [image: edit communities link]

Alternatively, go to the "Edit Profile & Settings" tab, then "Hide Communities".

> [image: edit profile... -> hide communities]

Both go to a page that lets you manage what communities are shown and hidden.

Comment: This works for me (but if/when closing future duplicates we should keep in mind that this might not work for others with a similar problem who want to keep other posts from that community in their lists, or who want to completely hide posts/communities from their profile *and* from the linked list)