# Can I hide a post from my top network questions? (Preferably without hiding an entire community)

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, network-profile, top-questions, top-network-posts

According to [my Stack Exchange Network Profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/4030991/steven-vascellaro), my third highest scoring question on the network is the English Language & Usage post *[What is a less controversial name for the clothing item known as a "wife-beater" in the United States?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/392966/224606)*

[image: Top network questions]

Understandably, I would like to hide this post from my profile, as not to be seen by potential employers.

The accepted answer for *[How to remove a specific post from "Top Network Posts"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256668/351462)* suggests hiding the entire community where the post was made, which feels a bit excessive.

I would also prefer not to remove my name from the post entirely, as was suggested for *[How do I remove my name from a post, in accordance with CC:WIKI?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732/351462)*

**Can an option be added to remove specific posts from "Top Network Posts" without having to hide an entire community?**

Comment: Seconded - this would be a useful feature. I don't like hiding an entire community when all I really want to hide is one post. Your title suggests you want to hide it just from your top network questions. I would go further and hide it from the profile entirely (which you do mention: "hide this post from my profile"). Maybe this question should be made more general if that is indeed your view.